# Tkinter .get() NameError: name 'entry' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

The important bits of my code are provided below. I am trying to use tkinter to make a nice GUI for a project I am working on. I decided to do a test to verify that I can access the data in the entry fields, and I am confused. I am having problems accessing the data of entry fields; I believe the problem is related to not utilizing self or self.master correctly. When I try to use the onGet() function, I get the error: "NameError: name 'rearTrack' is not defined". Can you please point me in the right direction. *I have deleted some lines that were not needed for this diagnosis. It was just a list of other labels and entrys.

```
class TireModelCalc(Frame):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.initUI()

def initUI(self):
    #GUI toolbar
    self.master.title("Tire Model Calc V1")

    menubar = Menu(self.master)
    self.master.config(menu=menubar)

    fileMenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=False)

    fileMenu.add_command(label='Open', underline=0, command=self.onOpen)
    fileMenu.add_command(label='Save', underline=0, command=self.onSave)
    fileMenu.add_command(label='Get', underline=0, command=self.onGet)
    fileMenu.add_separator()
    fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", underline=0, command=self.onExit)
    menubar.add_cascade(label="File", underline=0, menu=fileMenu)

    #GUI Inputs
    Label(self.master, text='Rear Track:', width=10, anchor=E).grid(row=5, column=0)

    rearTrack = Entry(self.master, width=5)

    rearTrack.grid(row=5, column=1)

def onExit(self):
    self.quit()

def onOpen(self):
    pass

def onSave(self):
    pass

def onGet(self):
    print(rearTrack.get())
```

Comment: Use `self.rearTrack = Entry(...)`, then you can use `self.rearTrack.grid(...)` and `self.rearTrack.get()`

Comment: @TheLizzard, your solution worked. I was pretty sure that I needed to use self.rearTrack.get(), but it did not work at first. Like you said, I also needed to save it as self.rearTrack; I am very new to the use of 'self'.

Comment: Do you want me to write a proper answer with a short explanation?

Comment: I was able to figure it out with the help you provided

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I'm not so sure what to say about your indentation.
However you may need to make rear track a global variable in order to be able to pass it from function to function.

Try that first if you don't know how to make global variables,
Let's say the variable is rearTrack, to make it a global variable,
Simply specify b4 initializing it as shown below

```
         global rearTrack
         rearTrack = " whatever you wish"
```

Comment: Why are you making a global variable when it should be an attribute of the class??? Also I think that it's a formatting problem and OP's code is correctly indented.

Comment: That was why I initially said I'm not sure about indentation. If it is within the class then it's a formatting error.

Comment: Notice the `self.initUI()`. It isn't going to work unless OP has the right indentation. Also they wouldn't be getting a `NameError` if they have an indentation problem. From that we can assume that OP doesn't know how to format the code correctly in stackoverflow.

Comment: Exactly and that's an issue. I'm in transit so I cant operate my pc

Comment: I just pasted in my code, not sure why it got messed up. It usually keeps the formatting. Either way, I don't think that making a global variable is the correct solution. @TheLizzard, your solution worked. I was pretty sure that I needed to use self.rearTrack.get(), but it did not work at first. Like you said, I also needed to save it as self.rearTrack; I am very new to the use of 'self'.